# How do I bind parameters to callbacks?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In C++, you have a `bind` function that allows you to bind parameters to functions. When you call the function, it will be called with those parameters. Similarly, MySQL has an ability to bind parameters to queries where it will substitute question marks with the variable. In Javascript and jQuery, the `bind` function has a confusingly different meaning. It makes the passed parameter the `this` variable, which is not at all what I want. Here's an example of what I want to achieve:

```
    var outerVariable;
    var callbacks = [
        some_object.event,
        some_object.differentEvent.bind(outerVariable)
    ];
    // func() will automatically have outerVariable in scope
    $.map(callbacks, function(func) { func(); });
```

Comment: `outerVariable` will be in scope regardless, since it is higher up the scope chain than `func`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is an easy way to use `bind` without playing around with `this`, if you want to bind arguments only you may be better writing a wrapper

```
function bindArgs(fn) {
    var slice = Array.prototype.slice,
        bound_args = slice.call(arguments, 1);
    return function () {
        var args = slice.call(arguments, 0);
        return fn.apply(this, bound_args.concat(args));
    }
}
```

Now

```
function foo(a, b) {
    console.log(this, a, b);
}
var bar = bindArgs(foo, 'bar');
var obj = {baz: bar};
obj.baz('baz'); // logs obj, "bar", "baz"
```

Answer (score 1):

Do this instead:

```
var callbacks = [
    some_object.event,
    some_object.differentEvent.bind(some_object, outerVariable)
];
```

Answer (score 1):

The only difference between the C++ and JavaScript `bind` is that the JavaScript `bind` takes one extra argument: `thisArg`, which will bind the keyword `this` for the bound function to whatever you pass in.  If you do not want to re-bind the `this`-argument, then pass null as the first parameter, and the rest should look familiar to the C++ variant you speak of:

```
function add(a, b) {
    return a + b
}

var three = add(1, 2)
var makeThree = add.bind(null, 1, 2)
three = makeThree()
```